# Comparing two files

Tags: c#, file, compare, whitespace, byte

I am comparing two files by reading them into filestream and comparing byte by byte. How can I skip whitespaces while comparing? I am using C#.net

Comment: Could you post your existing code and we can supply the changes?

Comment: If you didn't want to do the comparison yourself. You could use the FC.exe tool in windows, with the /W (compress/ignore whitespace) switch

Comment: In order to do this correctly you MUST know the encoding of the file. Is it plain 7 bit ASCII, UTF-8, UTF-16, encoded in some code page, what?

Comment: What I'm getting at is that basically, the operation you're performing here is logically inconsistent. You say you want to go byte by byte, but then do a character-by-character special case. That's logically inconsistent; bytes are not isomorphic to characters except in 7 bit ascii.  Why are you not doing your entire comparison character-by-character? Perhaps you can describe what goal you have; there's probably a better way to achieve it than what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
byte b;  

// ....

if (Char.IsWhiteSpace((char) b))
{
   // skip...
}
```

**EDIT**: As Eric Lippert points out, this is only correct if the encoding of the file is plain 7-bit ASCII. In any other encoding it will skip relevant bytes. So, you should take into account the encoding of your data.

Comment: This is only correct if the encoding of the file is plain 7 bit ASCII. In any other encoding it will skip relevant bytes.

Comment: @Eric Lippert: Hi, the poster said he was comparing bytes, but you are correct; he should be taking into account the encoding.